# Content Security Policy bypass

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss, content-security-policy

In the past few days, I tried to bypass CSP on a specific site.
As a last resort, I decided to ask here in the group :)

I have a site that I successfully accomplished to trigger XSS vulnerability.
The problem is that I have CSP that blocks my js from triggering.
I tested many methods in order to bypass the CSP but without any success so far.

---Example Payload---
[https://example.com/reviews/top/single/id/;%22>](https://example.com/reviews/top/single/id/;%22%3E)<a%20href='javascript:alert(1111)'>111111

Thanks.

CSP Settings:
[image: CSP Evaluator]
[image: CSP SCANNER]

Comment: https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Injector/blob/1e487f921561b03daf521c8c8c6dd3049edeb6de/src/selenium_injector/files/injector_extension/background.js#L46-L125 might give you a hint :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the point of CSP is that you can not bypass it. This is the point of it. If CSP blocks something, you did not find a vulnerability.

Comment: Hi,
I think you misunderstood my point.
I know that the CSP should provide more layers of security and block those kinds of attacks, despite this, it is difficult to apply it in the field in the correct way, and with this policy, I think it can be bypassed.
Another thing, it's like that you will say that if a website has a WAF so it well guarded against web application attacks and of course that it's far from the truth.
Anyone else that can provide accurate answers?

Comment: I think for asking questions like this, https://security.stackexchange.com/ is a better option.

Comment: Thanks, ill try my luck there.